# user input is asked for twice, only accepts second input

Tags: python, input, repeat

```
def main():
    add_triangle_check = 1
    while add_triangle_check > 0:
        print "test"
        add_triangle()
        add_triangle_check= add_triangle()

def add_triangle():
    add_triangle_check = 0
    user_input = raw_input("Do you want to add more triangles? Y/N")
    if user_input == ("y") or user_input == ("Y"):
        add_triangle_check = 1
    return add_triangle_check

main()
```

The above code returns the following:

> test
>
> Do you want to add more triangles? Y/N
>
> Do you want to add more triangles? Y/N

why is it repeating? I only need the user input once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called function add_traingle() twice.
Remove first add_traingle() and check if it works.

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out, don't know why I thought I needed that there, completely unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

nvm, I thought I had to add the function add_triangle to the while statment so it would repeat properly, by removing it everything is running smoothly